# Dynamically change td value angular 2

Tags: angular, primeng

I have a component that uses http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable and in that table after it is rendered the first time, I want to dunamically change some values in the `td`'s. I know that I should use `ElementRef` and `Renderer` from angular2, my problem is how can I for example change the value of all `td`s that have a class `test` to test or something similar and rerender the component. Any help is welcomed :)

Answer (score 0):

Proper way of doing this is having an array that is rendered as a table. Whenever you change the array the view is automatically rendered. Checkout the example: https://plnkr.co/edit/cPRQb2?p=preview.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
template: `<div class="ui-datatable-tablewrapper">
              <table class="undefined">
                  <thead class="ui-datatable-thead">
                      <tr class="ui-state-default">
                          <th class="ui-state-default ui-unselectable-text" >
                            <span class="ui-column-title">Vin</span>
                          </th>
                          <th class="ui-state-default ui-unselectable-text" >
                            <span class="ui-column-title">Year</span>
                          </th>
                          <th class="ui-state-default ui-unselectable-text" >
                              <span class="ui-column-title">Brand</span>
                          </th>
                          <th class="ui-state-default ui-unselectable-text" >
                              <span class="ui-column-title">Color</span>
                          </th>
                      </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody class="ui-datatable-data ui-widget-content">
                      <tr *ngFor="let row of data" class="ui-widget-content ui-datatable-even">
                          <td >
                              <span class="ui-cell-data">{{ row.col1 }}</span>
                          </td>
                          <td >
                              <span class="ui-cell-data">{{ row.col2 }}</span>
                          </td>
                          <td >
                              <span class="ui-cell-data">{{ row.col3 }}</span>
                          </td>
                          <td >
                              <span class="ui-cell-data">{{ row.col4 }}</span>
                          </td>
                      </tr>
                  </tbody>
              </table>
          </div><button (click)="changeValues()">Change Values</button>`
})
export class AppComponent{

  private data = [{
    col1: 'dsad231ff',
    col2: '2012',
    col3: 'VW',
    col4: 'Orange',
  },{
    col1: 'dsad231ff',
    col2: '2012',
    col3: 'VW',
    col4: 'Orange',
  },{
    col1: 'dsad231ff',
    col2: '2012',
    col3: 'VW',
    col4: 'Orange',
  },{
    col1: 'dsad231ff',
    col2: '2012',
    col3: 'VW',
    col4: 'Orange',
  }]

  constructor(){

  }

  changeValues(){
      this.data[0].col2 ="this value has changed";
      this.data[2].col3 ="this value has changed";
  }
}
```